# How to test class methods in RSPEC

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, rspec2

I wrote a simple class method `Buy.get_days(string)`, and is trying to test it with different text string inputs. However I feel it is very verbose.

- Is there any more concise way to test the following?
- Is there a
  equivalent of `subject` for **methods** which I can just keep passing
  different parameters in and check the results?
- Is there a way to avoid the unnecessary description at each `it`?

thanks

```
 describe Buy do
   describe '.get_days' do
    it 'should get days' do
      Buy.get_days('Includes a 1-weeknight stay for up to 4 people')
      .should == 1
      end
    it 'should get days' do
      Buy.get_days('Includes a 1-night stay in a King Studio Room with stone fireplace')
      .should == 1
    end
    it 'should get days' do
      Buy.get_days('Includes 4 nights/5 days at the Finisterra Hotel for up to two adults and two children (staying in the same room)')
      .should == 4
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How is the `it` description unnecessary? Just because you wrote the same text for specs that test different things doesn't mean the description shouldn't be there--maybe re-word them so they're useful?

Comment: the input/output combination is descriptive enough (for me at least).

Comment: can you give an example of rewording to make it more useful, @DaveNewton ?

Comment: @ahnbizcad Hopefully three different blocks, each of which `'should get days'` (e.g., they say the *same* thing), is an obvious smell. *Why* are the expectations different? There's something about them that makes the result be `1`, `1`, and `4`. The purpose of the string arg to `it` is to describe in human-readable terms what the block is actually testing. I can't reword the OP's descriptions because I don't know why the blocks should return the blocks that they do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://posterous.timocracy.com/a-pattern-for-testing-class-methods-in-ruby-w) is an interesting though perhaps more obtuse way to use the 'subject' block with Class methods.

Edit: The broken [link](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20120917073754/http://posterous.timocracy.com/a-pattern-for-testing-class-methods-in-ruby-w) as reported by the Wayback Archive which I suppose is susceptible to the same problem.

Comment: [broken link](http://posterous.timocracy.com/a-pattern-for-testing-class-methods-in-ruby-w) says "Posterous Spaces is no longer available"

Comment: Fast-forward three years and the gist is here: https://gist.github.com/knzconnor/816049

Comment: This is one reason why link-only answers are bad.

Answer (score 24):

Apparently there is a `described_class` method.

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/metadata/described-class

I suppose it's cleaner than `subject.class`, since it doesn't introduce another `.` method call, which reduces readability.

Using either `described_class` or `subject.class` may be more DRY than mentioning the class explicitly in every example. But personally I think not getting the syntax highlighting that comes with mentioning the class name explicitly is kind of a bummer, and I think it reduces readability, despite it totally winning in the maintainability department.

A question arises regarding best practice:

Should you use described_class whenever possible inside and outside the `.expect()` method, or only within the `expect()` method?

Comment: This is what I prefer to use in my tests, leaving subject for the data tested through said methods.

Answer (score 14):

There isn't a `subject` equivalent for calling a method, so using `it` is the way to go here. The issue I see with your code as presented is that it doesn't actually explain *what* you are testing for. I would write something more like:

```
describe Buy do
  describe '.get_days' do
    it 'should detect hyphenated weeknights' do
      Buy.get_days('Includes a 1-weeknight stay for up to 4 people').should == 1
    end
    it 'should detect hyphenated nights' do
      Buy.get_days('Includes a 1-night stay in a King Studio Room with stone fireplace').should == 1
    end
    it 'should detect first number' do
      Buy.get_days('Includes 4 nights/5 days at the Finisterra Hotel for up to two adults and two children (staying in the same room)').should == 4
    end
  end
end
```

I'm making assumptions about what you're after here, but hopefully the idea is clear. This will also lead to much more helpful error output when a test fails. Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess the answer at the end is: there is no more concise way of writing it.

Comment: @lulalala You don't *want* it to be concise, you want it to be accurate and descriptive in the context of the specs.

Answer (score 8):

This might be an old question but you can always use `subject.class` to get by:

```
describe Buy do
  describe '.get_days' do
    it { expect(subject.class.get_days('Includes a 1-weeknight stay for up to 4 people')).to eq 1 }
  end
end
```

Comment: Good catch! facepalm. I should have known this. This is the correct answer!

Comment: `subject.class`? Wouldn't it be clearer to use `Buy`?

Comment: @ahnbizcad Not really, because this shows only a single test. Think about the spec output and what it's supposed to be showing. Adding the other tests with no descriptive tests makes for essentially useless spec output because you don't know (a) what the spec is testing, and (b) what differentiates the different specs.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `subject`/`it` is to use `before`/`specify`:

```
describe '#destroy' do
  context 'with children' do
    before { @parent = FactoryGirl.create(:parent, children: FactoryGirl.create_list(:child, 2) }
    specify { @parent.destroy.should be_false }
  end
end
```

This will produce a reasonable description in RSpec's `-fd` output format:

```
#destroy
  with children
    should be false
```